# javascript - how to change canvas background from input

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm currently working on a project which we allow client to upload his map template and edit it. For example in an event, we want to put a booth in a map. We allow client to do that and right now I want to have my input as a background but I can't change it. If I change it locally it works fine.

```
  <input type="file" id="namebox1" onchange="preview(this)"> <br> <br>
  <button id="clickbutton" onclick="toCanvas()">Display</button>
  <img id="display" hidden>
```

```js
function preview(input) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("display").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

function changeBackground(){
    var img = document.getElementById('display')
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function `changeBackground()` to `toCanvas()` and use `url` to change the background:  `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";`

```js
function preview(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("display").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

function toCanvas() {
  var img = document.getElementById('display')
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
  img.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

```css
#display {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="namebox1" onchange="preview(this)"> <br> <br>
<button id="clickbutton" onclick="toCanvas()">Display</button>
<img id="display" >
```

Comment: It still doesn't appear. I try attach an image from outside using base64 in my function and its work fine. But, in this case I try to make it display an image from user input it doesn't show.

Comment: Did you removed the` hidden` tag from image and put it in `css` like this: `#display {visibility: hidden;
}` ?